# É possível montar um servidor que funcione a partir do meu computador?

Tags: delphi, servidor, conexão, chat

Tenho um chat feito em Delphi que funciona apenas em rede interna, tenho também o projeto dele caso queira fazer alguma alteração, e queria saber se é possível fazer com que este chat funcione em computadores de redes remotas a partir de um servidor montado no meu próprio PC, como exemplo, Apache ou qualquer outro tipo.

Comment: Quem deu -1, poderia explicar o pq?
+1, essa pergunta ajudará a muitas pessoas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível sim, porém não recomendado por questões óbvias: funcionamento 24h, segurança, estabilidade, garantia e qualidade de conexão, performance, energia, etc.

Hoje em dia é tão barato uma hospedagem ou uma VPS que não há por que hospedar em estrutura própria – seu custo final *provavelmente* (e efeitos colaterais) será muito maior hospedando em seu computador. Você não precisa nem registrar um domínio, podendo usar o IP do VPS diretamente.

Alguns serviços com preços acessíveis:

- http://www.win-vps.com/english/ (R$ 13)
- http://www.imperiohost.com.br/vps-windows.html

Comment: Você pode me indicar um serve gratuito para esta mesma funcionalidade?

Comment: @PascalStarting aqui tem um plano free por 6 meses: http://gratisvps.net/vpswindows.html

Comment: Tem esse aqui que já usei e é muito bom, com servidor no Brasil: http://www.host1plus.com.br/hospedagem-vps/

Answer (score 2):

Se cumprir isto:

1. Seu aplicativo cliente se conecta ao servidor, não o oposto;
2. Seu computador tem um IP real ou você pode configurar o seu roteador, ou mais de um se tiver (incomum mas existe), para encaminhar as requisições às portas atribuídas a seu aplicativo ou seu aplicativo pode configurar o roteador com uPnP (só funciona com um único roteador);
3. Seu IP externo é fixo ou você possui um serviço de DNS dinâmico ou cada vez que um cliente for se conectar ele saberá seu IP atualizado.

Certamente é possível.

Se são requisições `http` comuns, a porta `80` deve ser exposta para um ip real externo. Se forem `https`, a porta comum é a `443`. Pode ser qualquer porta que quiser, inclusive nem precisa ser a mesma porta externa e interna.

Estes números são configuração padrão, como o aplicativo é seu, pode escolher qualquer número, só configurar sua rede de acordo.

**Edição**

Concordo com a recomendação do AlfredBaudisch. +1 para a resposta dele.

Answer (score 2):

**A resposta curta é:**

Sim. É perfeitamente possível fazer isso acontecer. Você não precisa de nenhuma aplicação específica como o Apache. Tudo o que você precisa é de um roteador, saber o seu IP Público e redirecionar, no seu roteador, os pacotes vindos do IP Público em uma porta TCP específica para o IP interno do computador que está rodando o server do Chat. Esse redirecionamento de porta (Port Forward) é fundamental, a não ser que o chat esteja rodando no próprio roteador.

**A resposta longa é:**

Na rede interna, caso os computadores estejam na mesma sub-rede, fica fácil fazer com que eles se comuniquem. É o seu caso atual.

Entretanto, quando você deseja se comunicar com um computador que está dentro da sua casa, a partir de um computador que está fora da sua casa, as coisas ficam um pouco mais complicadas. A questão fundamental é que para se comunicar dessa maneira, você precisa saber o seu IP Público, ou seja, o IP que o provedor te fornece para que você consiga navegar na Internet a partir de sua casa.

É muito comum o provedor te fornecer também um roteador, pois isso permite que vários dispositivos que estão conectados na rede da sua casa, seja por wi-fi ou fio, naveguem na Internet de maneira simultânea. Além de saber o seu IP Público, você precisa saber em qual porta TCP o seu chat fica escutando (isso você já sabe).

Para você entender melhor, vamos chamar o computador fora da sua casa de **EXT** e o computador de dentro da sua casa de **INT**. O INT está conectado ao roteador de sua casa, chamado aqui de **ROT**.

**EXT** - Computador Externo - IP Público hipotético: 200.123.12.21

**ROT** - Roteador (ou gateway) que liga INT na Internet. IP Público hipotético: 179.79.12.12. IP Interno: 192.168.1.1

**INT** - Computador Interno - IP Interno hipotético: 192.168.1.23. Porta TCP hipotética que o server de chat está escutando: 3131

Basicamente funciona assim:

Objetivo: **EXT** deseja se conectar a um serviço de chat rodando na máquina **INT** que está na casa do @PascalStarting;

- **EXT** precisa saber o IP Público de **ROT**.
- **EXT** também precisa saber a porta que o serviço de chat está escutando.
- **EXT** então, com o client do chat, se conecta no 179.79.12.12:3131.
- O pacote enviado por **EXT** passar por vários roteadores até chegar em **ROT**.
- No momento que esse pacote chega em **ROT** ele é redirecionado para a porta 3131 no IP Interno 192.168.1.23 (o IP do **INT**)
- **INT** então recebe esse pacote, processa e responde. (Como o **INT** responde e esse pacote chega novamente no **EXT** deixo pra você pesquisar.)

Basicamente é isso. Existem questões interessantes a serem consideradas, como a segurança e disponibilidade como disse a outra resposta. Outra questão bem importante é que os provedores mudam o seu IP Público constantemente, portanto, ter um serviço de DDNS (Dynamic DNS ou DNS Dinâmico) configurado no roteador é fundamental.

Como forma de aprendizado, recomendo fortemente que você tente fazer isso, pois muito se aprenderá no processo.

A título de curiosidade, tenho um esquema deste tipo na minha casa. Consigo ligar um computador remotamente, trabalhar e depois desligá-lo, também remotamente. Porém, como sou chato com segurança, utilizo SSH Port Forward. O meu roteador é um TP-Link N750, rodando OpenWRT (Linux), portanto, consigo ter SSH e outros serviços que me permitem gerenciar a rede da minha casa de forma segura.

Comment: Resposta excelente!